# adding JButton to a specific column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add `JButton` to a `JTable` but instead of viewing the button it views(javax.swing......). What is the correct way to add a button?

```
public void setTableSize(ArrayList<CarRental> List)
{
    ArrayList<CarRental> ListToPrint= List;

    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) PrintListTable.getModel();

    model.setRowCount(0);

    EditButton n=new EditButton();
    Edit.addActionListener(n);

    for(int j=0;j<ListToPrint.size();j++)
    {           
        model.addRow(new String[]{j+"",ListToPrint.get(j).getName(),ListToPrint.get(j).getDays()+"",ListToPrint.get(j).getSize(),ListToPrint.get(j).getCarType(),ListToPrint.get(j).WithDriver(),ListToPrint.get(j).DailyFeesDetails(),ListToPrint.get(j).ComputeTotal()+"" });         
        model.setValueAt(Edit, j, 8);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only it were that easy. Presumably, you want the button to do something when clicked, so you have to set it as a cell editor as well as setting it as a cell renderer (your example just sets the `value` of the cell, not changing its renderer, so the default renderer is calling `toString()` on it).

Check out [this class](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) written by frequent SO contributor @camickr.